# Como personalizar Form gerado pelo CRUD do Symfony?

Tags: php, symfony-2, twig, crud

Estou alterando o template do Symfony para que o CRUD já tenha o formato que eu preciso, consegui alterar quase tudo, mas agora tinha a necessidade de alterar o form, para editar as classes de css e outros elementos com div e etc... para ficar de acordo com o layout que eu quero, os Controllers e as views do twig (edit.html.twig.twig, index.html.twig.twig, new.html.twig.twig, show.html.twig.twig e inclusive os actions.html.twig.twig e record_actions.html.twig) estão ok, mas para fazer o form eu vejo que há chamadas no código do twig para uma função form. Eu gostaria de saber onde eu posso mudar o template desse form, pois eu quero alterar o layout dele. Abaixo é um trecho do código do new.html.twig.twig.

```
{% block extends %}
    {{ "{% extends '::form.html.twig' %}" }} {% endblock extends %} {% block body %}
    {{ "{% block body -%}" }}
    <div class="content-wrapper-panel">
        <div class="panel form-horizontal">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <span class="panel-title">{{ entity }} creation</span>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                {{ '{{ form(form) }}' }}
            </div>
            <div class="panel-footer">
                {% set hide_edit, hide_delete = true, true %}
                {% include 'crud/views/others/record_actions.html.twig.twig' %}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    {{ "{% endblock %}" }} {% endblock body %}
```

Onde eu encontro o template que gerar o conteúdo de {{ form(form) }} e como personaliza-lo?

No edit.html.twig.twig ele cria o botão delete pelo seguinte comando:

```
{% if ('delete' in actions) and (not hide_delete) %}
        {{ '{{ form(delete_form) }}' }}
    {% endif %}
```

Só que adiciona algumas DIVs que eu quero remover, e deixar apenas o form e o button.

O trecho de código do edit que gera o botão delete produz a seguinte saída após renderizado o html:

```
<form name="form" method="post" action="/sbcorp/web/app_dev.php/city/2"><input type="hidden" name="_method" value="DELETE"><div id="form"><div><button type="submit" id="form_submit" name="form[submit]" class="btn btn-group">Delete</button></div><input type="hidden" id="form__token" name="form[_token]" value="cpQYW2u5jQ9eH-Ux7VOeKQMtERVno_T4h3Olshaw9js"></div></form>
```

Quero deixar apenas o form, os input hidden e o button

O local onde estou modificando o template da view está sendo mostrando conforme imagem abaixo. Já alterei todo o skeleton\crud\view e skeleton\crud\action

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Não recomendo alterar a base do sistema. Acredito que tenha uma maneira de extender em forma de macro essas funções, como no framework laravel, por exemplo. Caso atualize as dependências(composer update) todas essas alterações serão perdidas ou quem sabe, até tenham que ser ajustadas também.

Comment: @Lucas sua sugestão é válida, havia pensado nesse problema, a questão foi que eu não consegui encontrar uma outra solução em um primeiro momento e precisava criar um protótipo, os links que encontrei na internet me levaram inicialmente a essa solução, mas estou aberto a qualquer sugestão para melhorar isso. Até porque, realmente, se eu tiver que atualizar o componente minha implementação vai para o espaço, contudo nesse primeiro momento (enquanto não tenho uma solução melhor) é um risco aceitável e como ainda estou aprendendo a mexer, o conhecimento aqui também vai ser valido.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Não é necessário alterar os arquivos do framework. Para customizar a forma como os elementos de formulários são renderizados, é necessário copiar os arquivos dos templates para dentro dos arquivos da sua aplicação.

Leia esse artigo da documentação para saber mais a respeito:

http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_customization.html

Comment: Vou ler novamente e testar, sabe se é possível trabalhar com o skeleton da mesma forma, jogando para uma pasta e mandando buscar o modelo nele?

Comment: Sim, é exatamente essa a ideia. Já fiz muito isso adaptando templates para o Twitter Bootstrap.